# iOS: Looping json items to SESpringboard

Tags: ios, while-loop, items

So!  I have an NSDictionary that's pulling json out of my database just fine.  I also have a mutable array that creates items for my beautiful SESpringboard view.  The problem is that, initially, I only had a few items, so I was creating each item manually.  But now that I have THOUSANDS of items I want to do something like a "while" loop in php that would just keep creating items until it goes through the whole table.

Here's the code I've got:

```
Goods *g = [[Goods alloc] init];
g.GID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
g.GName = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"bk:%@",g.GName);                
g.GImg = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];                
g.GDesc = [dict objectForKey:@"description"];
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:g.GName imageName:g.GImg viewController:self removable:NO]];
SESpringBoard *thunderboard = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Boom" items:items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thor.png"]];
```

This works absolutely fine… except that what it does is place all the names and all the images one on top of another instead of creating a new item for each result.

If this were php I'd do something like "g.items" and it would just create a new item for each "g" but I'm not sure what to do here. Any help would be appreciated. (I googled but couldn't find anything like this for SESpringBoard items…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you parse your json in a variable named `allGoods`, and that it's an array containing dictionaries representing your "Goods" objects.

You can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in allGoods) {

    [items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] imageName:[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"] viewController:self removable:NO]];
}

SESpringBoard *thunderboard = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Boom" items:items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thor.png"]];
```

I removed your usage of "Goods *g", as it looks like you don't need to keep a reference to such an object.

---

EDIT: here is the 5 items limit you requested

The "MIN" in the for loop is just in case `allGoods` contains less than 5 items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MIN(5, allGoods.count); i++) {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [allGoods objectAtIndex:i];

    [items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] imageName:[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"] viewController:self removable:NO]];
}

SESpringBoard *thunderboard = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Boom" items:items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thor.png"]];
```

Comment: Wow… Quick AND accurate. When there are just a couple of items it woks fine. When there's more than that the view messes-up. But I guess that's my next question. THANKS for the help!

Comment: Can you, by any chance, tell me how to limit that to 5 results?

Comment: @mysticcola: still need an update for the 5 results limit ? Or did you find on your own ?

Comment: Still need. (Thought I wrote that hours ago... don't know why it didn't show...)

Comment: There you go. Let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.